# Passing ng-* attributes through to an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an Angular directive `<my-button>` in which I need to have it run another directive (`my-fun-directive`) on it's output, which is why I'm using `$compile` instead of a directive template.  Unfortunately it appears that doing it this way does not allow any additional HTML attributes or `ng-*`attributes to be passed through.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myButton', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var btnTxt = attrs.text || "";
            scope.buttonInnerHtml = attrs.icon ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + attrs.icon + '"></span> ' + btnTxt : btnTxt;
            var template = '<button type="button" class="myCustomClass" ng-bind-html="buttonInnerHtml" my-fun-directive></button>';

            var content = $compile(template)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(content);
        }
    };
});
```

**Usage**

```
<my-button
    icon="ok"
    text="Save Changes"
    class="anotherClass"
    ng-hide="someProperty"
    ng-click="myClickEvent()"
    example-directive></my-button>
```

**Current Output** (line breaks added for readability)

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="myCustomClass"
    ng-bind-html="buttonInnerHtml"
    my-fun-directive>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"><span> Save Changes
</button>
```

**Desired Output** (line breaks added for readability)

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="myCustomClass anotherClass"
    ng-bind-html="buttonInnerHtml"
    ng-hide="someProperty"
    ng-click="myClickEvent()"
    my-fun-directive
    example-directive>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"><span> Save Changes
</button>
```

Note the inclusion of the `ng-*` attributes, the additional directive, and the added CSS class.  How can I get all of this to work together?

Comment: why are you saying `which is why I'm using $compile instead of a directive template. ` ? you could have a directive declared in the template/templateUrl attribute of a directive.

Comment: @ps0604 yes I know, but the other directive I'm trying to use doesn't seem to be working when I do it that way... perhaps I need to look into this other directive a bit more before I blame it on this directive though...

Comment: why don't you post a plunk? that should work, you may have a different problem.

Comment: I was about to, but after some more testing I actually determined that my issue was totally unrelated from this & I was able to solve it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in HTML content of buttonInnerHtml. I got error "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.". When I fixed this all works fine:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <my-button
            icon="ok"
            text="Save Changes"
            class="anotherClass"
            ng-hide="someProperty"
            ng-click="myClickEvent()"
            example-directive></my-button>
    </body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []).directive('myButton', function ($compile, $sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var btnTxt = attrs.text || "";
                scope.buttonInnerHtml = attrs.icon ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + attrs.icon + '"></span> ' + btnTxt : btnTxt;
                scope.buttonInnerHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.buttonInnerHtml);
                var template = '<button type="button" class="myCustomClass" ng-bind-html="buttonInnerHtml" my-fun-directive></button>';

                var content = $compile(template)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(content);
            }
        };
    }).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    }]);
    </script>
</html>
```